# how to customize series datapoint labels with ms chart control

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

I have the following stacked column chart and I'm would like to customize the labels for the datapoints in each series so they were similar to '4:00 - 4:30 (class name)'  next datapoints in the series would be '4:30 - 5:00 (class name)' and so on.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[set labels on datapoints using mschart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909762/set-labels-on-datapoints-using-mschart)